# Принятие json ответа на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, платежи

Всем привет. Работаю с платежной системой AnyMoney. Пытаюсь реализовать такой функционал, чтобы в зависимости от статуса платежа изменялись данные в базе данных. При окончании платежа передается POST-метод в формате json, где содержится информация о платеже. Ответ приходит по определенному адресу. Я пытался отследить этот переход в web.php и перековал в контроллер:

```
Route::post('/payment', [RateController::class, 'payment'])->name('payment');
```

Но ответ не доходит до контроллера, и, следовательно не могу узнать статус платежа. Возможно есть те, кто сталкивался с этой проблемой. Буду очень благодарен. Работаю с Laravel 8.

Comment: Очень мало данных. Приведите пример обращения к роуту, что в консоли браузера пишется?

Comment: @LiudmilaSavateeva нет там никакой консоли браузера, это коллбэк от сервера.

Comment: Использую платежную систему AnyMoney. Когда пользователь совершил оплату, callback от сервера приходит по адресу https://findinvestor.me/payment. Для того чтобы отследить этот ответ, Route переводит на контроллер, в котором уже происходят манипуляции. Но до контроллера не доходит ответ. Мне нужно понять, как принять callback от сервера и уже в соответствии с этими данными, совершить какие-либо изменения. Вопрос в том, как принять этот ответ. Здесь есть документация по callback: https://docs.any.money/ru/callback/

Comment: вы возьмите постман или банально в браузере попробуйте отправить пост запрос на указанный адрес. скорее всего для начала получите про csrf-токен

Comment: Попробовал отправить POST-запрос самостоятельно. Если делать так, тогда в консоле появляется ошибка 500. Через Postman тоже появляется статус: 500 Internal Server Error. Callback от сервера пока тоже не доходит. CSRF-токен по этому адресу отключил. Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Для временной отладки APP_DEBUG = true поставьте, А то 500 ошибка сервера не информативна.

Comment: Как я понял, эта ошибка возникает не в Laravel, потому что, когда поставил APP_DEBUG = true, ничего не произошло. Например, в контроллере прописал dd($request). Когда отправляю запрос по этому адресу, все выводится, но возникает ошибка 500. Скорее всего из-за этого callback не доходит(потому что сервер ждет ответа 200)